# How to use entity names in an iframe srcdoc?

Tags: iframe

I have:

```
<iframe srcdoc="&lt;h1>Test&lt;/h1>"></iframe>
```

But it still comes out as:

## Test

How do I show it with the less than h1 greater than symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a result of attribute normalization in XML. One way to fix it is to...well, use more HTML entities to construct your HTML entities!

```
<iframe srcdoc="&amp;lt;h1>Test&amp;lt;/h1>"></iframe>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HmWMX/) to show it working. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I used this code and it seemed to work

```
<iframe srcdoc="&#60; h1 &#62; Test &#60; /h1 &#62;"></iframe>
```

Let me know if you have a problem with this.